# Пропорциональное изменение изображение

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть много изображений разного размера. Нужно все их уменьшить по ширине до 750px. Но чтобы  по высоте уменьшились пропорционально. Как вычислить какую устанавливать высоту в функции для ресайза?

Comment: поиск `Google` или поиск по `ХэшКоду` сломались?

Comment: либ разных тьма. выбирай любую. гугл в помощь

Comment: ууууу, и не стыдно вам с такими познаниями математики лезть к программированию?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да этому же в пятом классе учат. Пусть до ресайза размер был W x H, после ресайза w x h. Нужно, чтобы изображения были подобны. Получаем W / w = H / h, откуда h = H * w / W. В вашем случае h = 750 * H / W.